# Logging the XML or JSON sent by RestSharp

Tags: restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to send information to a API. I would like to log the XML that I've sent to this API so I can debug later.

I would like to do something like this:

```
var request = new RestRequest(resourcePath, method);
request.AddBody(dto);
Logger.Log(request.Content);
var response = Client.Execute(request);
```

But, the actual request sent by RestSharp does not seem to be exposed.

Comment: If you want to debug later, I think this could be more useful than logging only the body: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37319687/5478655

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything sent in the request is available in request.Parameters.

To make getting the request body easier I created this extension method:

```
public static class RestSharpExtensions
{
    public static string GetBody(this IRestRequest request)
    {
        var bodyParameter = request.Parameters
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody);
        return bodyParameter == null
            ? null
            : bodyParameter.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you passed an object for RequestBody, getting the ToString() of the Value does not contain raw request body text, it only returns the name of the object.