# Access a REST API with C#

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I try to access to the REST API from NetExplorer. It works when I send a request with postman :

[image]

But It doesn't with my C# code :

```
var client = new RestClient("https://patrimoine-click.netexplorer.pro/api/auth");

        var ReqAuth = new { user = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" };

        JsonResult result = new JsonResult(ReqAuth);
        
        var request = new RestRequest(result.ToString(), Method.Post);
        
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        
        RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

Here's the error message :

{"error":"Il n'existe aucune m\u00e9thode de l'API pouvant r\u00e9pondre \u00e0 votre appel."}

In english, **there's no API method to resolve your call**

If somebody can help me ...

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to use some kind of HTTP request monitoring tool, like fiddler, to see the difference between your two calls.

Comment: Use fiddler (or fiddler like app) to monitor the https call. But, can you try to set json body using standard RestSharp method like that: `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddJsonBody(new { user = "xxxxxx", password = "xxxxxxx" });`? JsonResult is not the best way to send a payload to an api using RestSharp!

Comment: You can print the request details like headers and compare that with what happens in Postman. For printing http headers of Restsharp , see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683858/restsharp-print-raw-request-and-response-headers)

Comment: I don't think that this is how you add a JSON Body in RestSharp. See: https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#addstringbody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the constructor of RestRequest wrong, the constructor does not take in the content (body) like that. Try using it with AddJsonBody like so:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://patrimoine-click.netexplorer.pro/api/auth");
var ReqAuth = new { user = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" };
 
var request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = RestSharp.Method.Post;
request.AddJsonBody(ReqAuth);
    
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    
RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

Documentation: https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#request-body

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now, I can go on now with the other API methods  :D